# SQLite экспорт выборки в JSON

Tags: json, sqlite

Очеедной глупый вопрос, ответ на который не смог найти в "ГУГЛ":

```html
SELECT docs.date, docs.typeId, rows.docId, docTypes.removed, docs.removed
FROM docs, docTypes, products, rows
WHERE docTypes.removed <> 1 and docs.removed <> 1
ORDER BY docs.date;
```

вот такая у меня выборка из базы данных. Во-первых проблема в том, что результатов слишком много и не все выводятся в консоли. Во-вторых, мне необходимо экспортировать эти результаты в формате JSON.
И есть ли возможность получать результаты каждого запроса в виде файла?

Answer (score 1):

Всё получилось с использованием DB Browser for SQLite